# How to append string to Jenkins variable "BUILD_URL"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using [Cppcheck Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Cppcheck+Plugin). I am trying to send `Cppcheck Results` URL in email once the Jenkins job is completed.

I tried setting `Default Content` to following:

```
View this URL for Cppcheck Results: $BUILD_URL + "cppcheckResult/"
```

But the email which I got had following text:

```
View this URL for Cppcheck Results: https://myurl/job/fscopy/7/+"cppcheckResult/"
```

Can someone help me figuring out how can I send correct URL in email which is following:

```
https://myurl/job/fscopy/7/cppcheckResult/
```

Comment: did you try single quote ??

Comment: Single quote also dint work, gave the same output in email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolved it by creating `CPPCHECK` environment variable and using it as below:

```
View this URL for Cppcheck Results: $BUILD_URL$CPPCHECK
```

which gave me output in email as following:

```
View this URL for Cppcheck Results: https://myurl/job/fscopy/7/cppcheckResult/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate without any spaces in-between using `${BUILD_URL}cppcheckResult/`